# Banach space dual to $L^\infty(I,H^1(M))$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

What is the dual to $L^\infty (I,H^1(M))$?, where $I$ is an interval in the real line; $H^1(M)$ is Sobolev space of degree 1, and $M$ is a compact manifold like the torus.

Any references that show that is appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be the space $\mathcal{M}(I, H^{-1}(M))$, where $\mathcal{M}$ denotes the space of bounded Radon measures and $H^{-1}$ is the dual of $H^1$. In short, "compose" the dual spaces in the same order. For a proof, I guess you could try to mimic the usual one which shows that $(L^{\infty})^* = \mathcal{M}$. (At least, it is rather clear that the suggested space acts canonically on your space.)

Comment: Do you have a reference for such a proof as you described?

Comment: Various questions on M.SE and MO asked for such results, [here is one of them](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47395/the-duals-of-l-infty-and-l-infty). (And now I wonder whether I messed up the dual of $L^{\infty}$ with that of $\mathcal{C}_0$. That's quite possible.)

Comment: @Hachino The dual of $L^\infty$ is **much** bigger than ${\mathcal M}$. ${\mathcal M}$ would be the dual of $C(I)$ (assuming $I$ is compact).

Comment: @YemonChoi Okay, I indeed messed it up, sorry for that. Going back to the original question, does $(L^{\infty})^*(I, H^{-1}(M))$ sound like a reasonable dual space ?

Comment: Well, "vector-valued $(L^\infty)^*$" doesn't seem well-defined to me. But I think the OP needs to clarify whether he really wants the full dual, or just something like a predual

Comment: I need the dual for the theorem of Alaoglu, where I need to find the Banach space to which $L^\infty(I,H^1(M))$ is dual to. Please also provide me with references for proof of your claims.

Comment: @Alan: That is a very different question - you aren't looking for the dual but the predual.  The answer is almost certainly going to be $L^1(I, H^1(M))$ and the proof will probably look very similar to the proof that $L^1(I, \mathbb{R})^* = L^\infty(I, \mathbb{R})$.  The canonical reference for any question like "what is the dual of Banach space $X$" is Dunford and Schwartz, *Linear Operators*.  Another possible place to look is Dinculeanu's *Vector Measures*.

Comment: In the spirit of the remark of Nate Eldredge, it seems clear that you looking for a predual and it may be worth remarking that one can always identify the dual of a Bochner space $L^1(E)$ of integrable functions with values in a general Banach space with a space of equivalence classes of functions with values in $E'$ which are bounded and measurable in a suitable sense.  The result is particularly simple to state when $E$ is separable and reflexive as in your situation---then one gets the space of equivalence classes of bounded, measurable functions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems clear from the above comments, in particular your mention of Alaoglu, that what you are looking for is a Banach space whose dual is naturally identifiable with the one in your query.  Such a space is the corresponding $L^1$-space with values in $H^1$.  This follows immediately from Theorem 1 on p. 96 of the classic "Vecor measures" by Diestel and Uhl.  (The specific  form of your image space is a bit of a red herring---the important fact is that it is a Hilbert space and so has the Radon Nikodym property).

Two remarks: If you really want a dual, rather than a predual, then there is an explicit description as a space of vector-valued finitely additive measures.  And there is a slight ambivalence when talking about the dual of $H^1$.  As a Hilbert space, it is self-dual but in the context of Sobolev spaces it is more usual to regard $H^{-1}$ as the dual. This does not materially affect the above response.